# why my code have to call the function 2 times to get the correct value?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I call a function with the following codes on the client side, post the array to server side.
but the server side responses 0 for the return value first. I have to call the function again, then it returns the correct value. wondering if anyone know what is wrong with my code? thx!

**client side:**

```
var array = [];
array.push(1, 2, 3);

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnedScore).calScore(array);
function returnedScore(value) {
score = value;
return score;
}
```

**server side:**

```
function calScore(array) {
var value = 0;
value = array[0] - 5*array[1]*array[2]*2;
return value; 
}
```

Comment: What is the value passed to the server side? Can you post the input data

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function launchMyStupidDialog() {
  let html='<div id="msg"></div>';
  html+='<script>var array = [];array.push(1, 2, 3);google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnedScore).calScore(array);function returnedScore(value) {document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=value;console.log(value);}</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'test');
}

function calScore(array) {
var value = 0;
value = array[0] - 5*array[1]*array[2]*2;
return value; 
}
```

[image]